# Can I access the "Item" custom meta (metadata fields) in a Storage Extension?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, java, metadata, storage-extensions

I am trying to determine whether I need to process anything in my Storage Extension depending on certain fields in the item metadata. (I am extending all 3, Page, ComponentPrensentation and Binary DAOs).

What is the correct way to "load" the item (Page, Component and Binary) custom meta within an Storage extension? Am I not supposed to do that? In previous "deployer" extensions I could easily create an instance of the `PageMetaFactory`, `BinaryMetaFactory` or `ComponentPresentationMetaFactory` and then access the custom meta. Is that no longer *the right way*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Jaime - did you ever get anywhere with this?